# Issue with solution of an classical angular momentum problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

I was doing a Introductory physics homework. On a frictionless table two ideal strings with masses at their ends can spin freely as seen in the figure.
[image: esta wea ne tuebe cgati]

Then, both masses collide elastically. I have to derive the following relation $a^2m_1(\omega_1-\omega')=b^2m_2(\omega_2'-\omega)$ being $\omega'$ the angular velocity after the collision.

So my teacher uses conservation of angular momentum, adding the *scalar* shape of both angular moments with respect to their *centers* of rotation. But, this is correct? I mean, he taught us all the physics on the vectorial form, so doing the problem without explaining what he did confuses me. Aren't we supposed to first choose an origin to calculate the angular momentum?

This is how my professor does the exercise: $\sum L=a^2m_1\omega_1+b^2m_2\omega_2$

How i suposse that can i solve the problem:
$\sum L=\vec{r_{1O}}\times\vec{p}_1+\vec{r_{2O}}\times\vec{p}_2$
being $O$ an arbitrary origin.

Comment: I do not think the angular momentum of $m_1$ with respect to point A plus the the angular momentum of $m_2$ with respect to point B, is conserved.  Please see my updated answer.  (I share your concern about not using a common reference point for evaluating the angular momentum.)

Comment: The test would be to calculate this situation as a linear elastic collision, and then check to see of any calculation with angular momentum agrees with that. (If the algebra gets to complex, put in some numbers.)

Comment: @ R.W. Bird  I did the check you recommend (see my answer) and unless I made a mistake the approach using different origins for the two angular momenta is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about this more, I ***do not think*** the the angular momentum of $m_1$ about A plus the angular momentum of $m_2$ about B is conserved.

Here is how I solve the problem using $\tau \enspace\Delta t = \Delta L$, where $\tau$ is torque and $L$ is angular momentum. For $m_1$ considering the torque about A due to the collision, $F_{m_2onm_1}\enspace a \enspace \Delta t = m_1a^2(\omega _1^{'} - \omega _1)$.  For $m_2$ considering the torque about B, $F_{m_1onm_2} \enspace b\enspace \Delta t = m_2b^2(\omega _2^{'} - \omega _2)$. $F_{m_1onm_2} = -F_{m_2onm_1}$. So $m_1a(\omega _1^{'} - \omega _1) = - m_2b(\omega _2^{'} - \omega _2)$.

You obtain the same answer using the conservation of linear momentum:    $m_1(v_1^{'} - v _1) + m_2(v _2^{'} - v_2) = 0$ since $v_1 = a\omega_1$ and $v_2 = b\omega_2$. (The tension forces on the masses from the strings are negligible compared to the force of impact during the collision.  After the collision the string tensions just restrict the motion to circular.)

I *do not think* the the angular momentum of $m_1$ about A plus the angular momentum of $m_2$ about B is conserved.  (I share your concern about not using a common point for evaluating the angular momentum.)

For an elastic collision, kinetic energy is also conserved, and that along with the earlier relation allows you to solve for $\omega_1 ^{'}$ and $\omega_2 ^{'}$ in terms of $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$.

Trying to solve for the angular momentum using a common point, say A, is complicated since you have the "hinge" force/torque at B to consider, as pointed out earlier by @ SteelCubes.

See [If a ball spinning on a rod hits another ball, what is conserved linear or angular momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129869/if-a-ball-spinning-on-a-rod-hits-another-ball-what-is-conserved-linear-or-angul) on this exchange.

Comment: But, by the right hand rule, $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ have the same direction. And my relation it's um, $\vec{L}_1$ + $\vec{L}_2$ but both seen from a common origin, i don't see any errors, i guess

Comment: Yes, my mistake;  $\omega _1$ and $\omega _2$ are in the same direction (into the page). But, I completely re-worked my answer.

Comment: That's why i'm concerned, because the conservation of angular momenta and the election of origin. But i'm curious, why do you change your mind about that the angular momenta doesn't conserve?

Comment: When I solved using torques and using linear momentum the result (see my updated answer) does not agree with assuming conservation of angular momentum using different origins for the two masses.  I really think you have to use a common origin for the angular momentum approach and that involves complexity due to the hinge forces as others previously discussed.

Comment: During the collision the sting tensions are negligible, so it's as if two balls moving freely collide.  The string tensions just restrict the motions before and after the collision.  I searched numerous advanced physics mechanics books and they always use a common origin for evaluating torques and angular momentum for a system of particles; all of their derived relationships for conservation of angular momentum use a common origin.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, angular momentum is a vector quantity and you got it right. What you missed is angular momentum is perpendicular to the plane of motion. And here, both the collisions and the independent motions of the ball are occurring in the same plane (lets say, plane of your notebook). So, the angular momenta must be in the direction perpendicular to the plane of notebook. (I am already assuming you got it- why angular momentum is conserved). So, here, you're left with 2 vector quantities (angular momenta of ball 1 and ball 2) directed along same line. (Hope it doesn't confuse you, but angular momentum is a free vector. So, all parallel and anti-parallel angular momentum vectors can be treated to be vectors along the same line). Let's assume this direction ***<sup>^</sup>n*** . And you must be knowing that a vector directed along ***<sup>^</sup>n*** of magnitude A is A (***<sup>^</sup>n***) and A is a scalar. And any parallel vector can be added or subtracted to it as if they were scalars as well.

Comment: The choose of origin matters? I mean, he added the angular momenta about their centers. But if i add the angular momenta about an arbitrary origin to both of the masses, i'll solve the problem anyways?

Comment: In my opinion, YES, BUT ACTUALLY NO! If you try to choose a new origin and calculate the angular momentum about that point, you MAY be able to solve the problem using conservation of angular momentum. The only thing is, if the origin is taken somewhere else, there would be a torque of HINGE REACTION acting upon the system (even if you escape the angular impulse of collision by taking them as a system). But what if instead of taking "a" origin, you instead calculate the angular momentum about the point around which the pure rotation takes place? That's what your teacher did.

Comment: @johnbear02 you'll get more clarity on the concept of instantaneous axes of rotation, pure rotatory motion about hinged point, collisions and need of considering angular momentum about axes instead of points (especially for visualization purposes) as you will spend more time visualising these problems

Comment: I mean, i understand that using the center of rotations it's very convenient, but what it the basis behind it? Is it not "rigorous"?

Comment: Its nothing like rigorous, but a mere logic. The logic being said, "THE EFFECT OF HINGE REACTION". As the balls collide, they apply force on each other. The force was supposed to move the ball and the rod in the direction of its application. But the point where the rod is pinned to the ground, refuses to displace or even gain a momentary acceleration. This call for the need of a force to balance the effect of collision. This force is applied by the hinged point and hence is named hinge reaction. This force can apply torque at any arbitrarily chosen point, unless the point is where it acts.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: btw, you can obtain a similar equation if you conserve the rotational kinetic energy (the collision being elastic). Try it yourself.